# Special values of the Dedekind eta function

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, infinite-product

Does anyone know of an article or a book which contains a comprehensive list of some known explicit values of the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$?

Comment: Check
Additional values of Dedekind's $\eta$ function in radical form - Mathematics Stack Exchange

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101157/