# Additional values of Dedekind's $\eta$ function in radical form

Tags: radicals, modular-forms

Can anyone confirm the following values of the $\eta $ function to increase the table of the post
[What is the exact value of $\eta(6i)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334684/what-is-the-exact-value-of-eta6i) ?

$\eta(6i)=\frac{1}{2^{11/8}3^{3/8}}\big(2-\sqrt{3}\big)^{1/24}\big(\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4}\big)^{1/4}
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(7i)=\frac{1}{2^{13/8}7^{7/16}}\sqrt{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}-\sqrt{-7+3\sqrt{7}}}
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(8i)=\frac{1}{2^{73/32}}\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/8}\big(2^{1/4}-1\big)^{1/2}
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(9i)$  = $\frac{1} {6} \big(\sqrt{6}\, (2+\sqrt{3})^{1/6} -3 \big)^{1/3} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(10i) = \frac {1} {2^{11/8}  \sqrt{5}  \varphi^{1/2}} \frac {5^{1/4}-1} {\sqrt{2}}  \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

where $\varphi$ is *golden ratio*.

$\eta(11i)=\frac{1}{2^{13/12}*3^{1/4}*11^{11/24}}\Big(4*22^{1/3}-(306 \sqrt{33}-837\sqrt{3}-351\sqrt{11}+1490)^{1/3}-(-306 \sqrt{33}+837\sqrt{3}-351\sqrt{11}+1490)^{1/3}\Big)^{1/4}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

[A modular equation of 11th degree of Dedekind's $\eta$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205345/a-modular-equation-of-11th-degree-of-dedekinds-eta-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$\eta(12i) = \frac  {1} {2^{31/16} 3^{3/8}} (2+\sqrt{3})^{5/48} (\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4})^{3/8} (\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/4} (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{1/4} (3^{1/4}-1)^{1/2} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$.

$\eta(13i)=\frac{1} {2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{13} }  \sqrt{ -5- (15 \sqrt{39}+39 \sqrt{3}-18 \sqrt{13}-91 )^{1/3}+ (15 \sqrt{39}+39 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{13}+91)^{1/3}} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

[A modular equation of 13th degree of Dedekind’s $ \eta$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205373/a-modular-equation-of-13th-degree-of-dedekind-s-eta-function)

$\eta(14i)=\frac{1} {2^{11/4} 7^{7/16}} \big(\sqrt{\sqrt{3\sqrt{7}-7}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{27\sqrt{7}-7}-\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}+21}}\big) \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(15i)=\frac{1} {4 \sqrt{10}* 3^{3/8}}(\sqrt{5}-2)^{1/2}(2-\sqrt{3})^{11/12} \big(\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}-15^{1/4}} {2} \big)^{2} (540^{1/4}+60^{1/4}+2) \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(16i)=\frac{1}{2^{177/64}}\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)^{1/16}\big(2^{1/4}-1\big)^{1/4}
\big(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}-2^{5/8}\big)^{1/2}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(17i)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{34}} \sqrt{272^{1/8}\big(\sqrt{61-7\sqrt{17}}-\sqrt{5\sqrt{17}+17}\big)-17^{3/4}+3\sqrt{17}-17^{1/4}-1} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

[A modular equation of 17th degree of Dedekind’s $\eta$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205410/a-modular-equation-of-17th-degree-of-dedekind-s-eta-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$\eta(18i)=\frac{1} {2^{91/72} 3} \frac{\big(1-(2. 108^{1/4}-2\sqrt{3}-2)^{1/3}\big)^{1/3}} {\big(( 3.12^{1/4}+108^{1/4}+2\sqrt{3}+4)^{1/3}+2^{1/3}\big)^{1/3}} \big((6\sqrt{3}+18)^{1/3}-3\big)^{1/3} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(18i) =\frac{1} {2^{11/8}*3^{2/3}}\Big(\big(-\frac{5*12^{1/4}}{6}+\frac{7*\sqrt{3}}{9}+\frac{108^{1/4}}{6}+\frac{2}{3}\big)^{1/3}-1\Big)^{1/3} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

Thanks to Vladimir Reshetnikov

[A modular equation of 19th degree of Dedekind’s $\eta$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205515/a-modular-equation-of-19th-degree-of-dedekind-s-eta-function)

$\eta(19i)=\frac{1}{20. 2^{7/4}.19^{3/8}.1203^{1/4}} \Big( 100680000 +7361892000 \gamma+76992000 \sqrt{19} \gamma -1888138300 \gamma^{2}+145028140\gamma^{3}-4533799 \gamma^{4}\Big)^{1/4} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

with

$$\small\begin{align}
\alpha &=30 \sqrt{198616747730+65513019062 \sqrt{5}},\\
\beta &=30 \sqrt{198616747730-65513019062 \sqrt{5}},\\
\eta &=\sqrt[5]{11410567+2790935 \sqrt{5}+\alpha\;}+\sqrt[5]{11410567+2790935 \sqrt{5}-\alpha\;}\\
&+\sqrt[5]{11410567-2790935 \sqrt{5}+\beta\;}-\sqrt[5]{2790935 \sqrt{5}-11410567+\beta\;},\,\text{and}\\
\gamma& =8-\left(\frac{2}{19}\right)^{4/5} \eta.
\end{align}$$

$\eta(20i)=\frac{1} {2^{29/16}.\sqrt{5}} (\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/2} (5^{1/4}- \sqrt{2})^{1/2} (\sqrt{10}-3)^{1/4} \big(\frac{5^{1/4}-1} {\sqrt{2}}\big)^{3/2} \varphi^{1/4} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(20i)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{5}.2^{31/16}}\Big(-102.5^{1/4}+6.5^{3/4}+69\sqrt{5}-14\sqrt{2}+6\sqrt{10}-21\Big)^{1/8}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(21i)=\frac{1} {2^{11/8} 7^{7/16}\sqrt{3}}  \frac{z a} {b c^{2} d e^{1/3}}
 \big(1+2\sqrt{2} \frac{b^{3/2} d^{3/2} e^{1/2}} {a^{3/2} c^{6}} \big)^{1/4}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}-252^{1/8}$$

$$b==\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}+252^{1/8}$$

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}+7^{1/4}} {2}$$

$$d=\frac{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}} {2}$$

$$e=2+\sqrt{3}$$

$$z=\sqrt{\sqrt{13+\sqrt{7}}+\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{7}}}$$.

$\eta(22i)=\frac{(a-b-c)^{1/4}}               
 {2^{35/24}*3^{1/4}*11^{11/24}*\sqrt{G}}*\big(G^{12}-\sqrt{G^{24}-1}\big)^{1/8}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$G=\frac{r(s+t)+2}{3*\sqrt{2}};$$
$$r=(3*\sqrt{11}+11)^{1/3};$$
$$s=(3*\sqrt{11}+3*\sqrt{3}+4)^{1/3};$$
$$t=(3*\sqrt{11}-3*\sqrt{3}+4)^{1/3};$$
$$a=4*22^{1/3};$$
$$b=(306*\sqrt{33}-837*\sqrt{3}-351*\sqrt{11}+1490)^{1/3};$$
$$c=(-306*\sqrt{33}+837*\sqrt{3}-351*\sqrt{11}+1490)^{1/3};$$

Thanks to Vladimir Reshetnikov

[A modular equation of 23rd degree of Dedekind’s $\eta$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205555/a-modular-equation-of-23rd-degree-of-dedekind-s-eta-function)

$\eta(23i)=\frac{1}{2^{13/12}\cdot 3^{1/4}\cdot \sqrt{23}}
\Big(\alpha^{1/3}+\frac{B^{2}-A^{2}}{\alpha^{1/3}}+2B\Big)^{1/4}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

with
$$\alpha=32\sqrt{23}(38-9\sqrt{3})+2^{2}\cdot3^{3}\cdot23(9\cdot\sqrt{3}-4)-9\sqrt{2}23^{1/4)}(-454\sqrt{3}+139\sqrt{23}+62\sqrt{69}+717)$$

$$A=\frac{\sqrt{3}23^{1/8}(8920771 \cdot 23^{1/4}-702648\cdot 23^{3/4}+12400065\cdot \sqrt{46}-50943951\cdot \sqrt{2})^{1/6}}{2^{2/3}}$$

$$B=\frac{23^{1/4}(9+3 \cdot \sqrt{23}-2\cdot 92^{1/4})}{2^{7/6}}$$

$\eta(24i) =\frac{\sqrt{d}*c^{1/4}*e^{1/8}*f^{1/4}}  {2^{75/32}*3^{3/8}*a^{3/8}*b^{1/12}}*\sqrt{b^{1/16}*c^{3/8}-\sqrt{2a*f}*e^{1/4}}\phi^{1/4} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$a=\sqrt{2}-1; b=2-\sqrt{3};  c=\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4};  d=2^{1/4}-1;  e=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2};  f=3^{1/4}-1$

$\eta(25i)=\frac{1} {10} \Big(A^{1/5}-B^{1/5}-1 \Big)           \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$A=\sqrt {(\frac{9 \sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{45}{2} )}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{9}{2}$

$B=\sqrt{\frac{9\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{45}{2} }-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{9}{2}$

$\eta(25i)=\frac{1} {10} \Big(-1 + (4+\varphi+3*5^{1/4}\sqrt{\varphi})^{1/5}+(4+\varphi-3*5^{1/4}\sqrt{\varphi})^{1/5}
\Big)
          \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(25i)=\frac{1} {40 \varphi^{10}} \big(     1+(4\varphi)^{1/5}    \big(     (3+\frac{5^{1/4}} { \varphi^{3/2}}  )^{1/5}  +  (3-\frac{5^{1/4}} { \varphi^{3/2}}  )^{1/5} )\big).  
\big(1+\varphi^{3} \big(    1-(4/\varphi)^{1/5}    \big(      (3+5^{1/4} \varphi^{3/2})^{1/5}   +    (3-5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2})^{1/5} \big) \big)^{2}\big)^{2}      \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

where $\varphi$ is *golden ratio*.

$\eta(26i)=\frac{\sqrt{-A+B-5}} {\sqrt{39}*2^{11/8}*\sqrt{G}}*\Big(G^{12}-\sqrt{G^{24}-1}\Big)^{1/8}*\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$G=\frac{\sqrt{a+b+26}+\sqrt{a+b+14}}  {2*\sqrt{3}}; $$ $$a=(10673-936*\sqrt{3})^{1/3};$$

$$b=(10673+936*\sqrt{3})^{1/3};$$
$$A=(15*\sqrt{39}+39*\sqrt{3}-18*\sqrt{13}-91)^{1/3};$$
$$B=(15*\sqrt{39}+39*\sqrt{3}+18*\sqrt{13}+91)^{1/3}.$$

$\eta(27i)=\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^{1/6}} {2^{13/12}*3^{95/72}}\frac{\Big(-3^{5/6}\big((48\sqrt{3}-72)^{1/3}+(16\sqrt{3}-16)^{1/3}+3\sqrt{3}-3\big)^{1/3}+(72-24\sqrt{3})^{1/3}+4^{1/3}\Big)^{1/3}       }  
{ \big((48\sqrt{3}-72)^{1/3}+(16\sqrt{3}-16)^{1/3}+3\sqrt{3}-3\big)^{1/9} }\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(27i)=\frac{\Big(-3^{5/6}*a^{5/9}+\big(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}*a^{1/6}\big)^{1/3}*\big(2*\sqrt{3}*a^{1/6}+\sqrt{2}\big)\Big)^{1/3}}      {3^{23/72}*a^{11/108}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=2-\sqrt{3}$$

$\eta(27i)=\frac{a^{1/12}}{6*3^{1/24}}\Big(-1+\big(+1+
\frac{\big(\sqrt{3}a^{1/6}-\sqrt{2}\big)^{4}}{3^{5/2}a^{5/3}}\big)^{1/3}\Big)^{1/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=2-\sqrt{3}$$

$\eta(28i)=\frac{1}{2^{29/16}*7^{7/16}}   \frac{   \sqrt{  8*\sqrt{m-n}+ ( \sqrt{n+p}-\sqrt{q-r}  )^{3}} -2*\sqrt{2}*(m-n)^{1/4}  }    
{a^{1/4}*(m-n)^{1/12}}*\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=\sqrt{2}-1;m=\sqrt{83-31*\sqrt{7}};n=\sqrt{3*\sqrt{7}-7};p=\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}};$$

$$q=\sqrt{27*\sqrt{7}-7};r=\sqrt{7*\sqrt{7}+21}.$$

$\eta(30i)=\frac{1}{\color{blue}{4}\sqrt{5}.2^{7/8}.3^{3/8}} \frac{c\Big(a^{4}b^{12}\varphi^{12}-\sqrt{ a^{8}b^{24}\varphi^{24}-1}\Big)^{1/8}} {\varphi^{2}a^{13/12}b^{5/2}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

where $\varphi$ is *golden ratio*, $a=2+\sqrt{3}$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}+15^{1/4}}{2}$ and
$c=540^{1/4}+60^{1/4}+2.$

$\eta(32i)=\frac{1} {8.2^{33/128}}\frac{ (2^{1/4}-1)^{1/8} (\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} – 2^{5/8} )^{5/4} } { ( \sqrt{2}+1)^{1/32} (2^{1/4}+1+2^{13/16} (\sqrt{2}+1)^{1/4} )^{1/2} } \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(35i)= \frac{\sqrt { \sqrt{7+3 \sqrt{7}} + \sqrt{13+ \sqrt{7}}}}
 {\sqrt{5} . 2^{11/8}.7^{7/16} \varphi^{2}. \sqrt{b}. c^{3}.  d^{2}} \sqrt{1+2  \frac{ \varphi  b ^{1/4} d}  {c^{7/2} } }
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

where $\varphi$ is *golden ratio*

$$b=6+\sqrt{35}$$

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}+7^{1/4}}  {2}$$

$$d=\sqrt{\frac{43+15 \sqrt{7}+(8+3\sqrt{7})\sqrt{10 \sqrt{7}}} {8}}+\sqrt{\frac{35+15 \sqrt{7}+(8+3\sqrt{7})  \sqrt{10 \sqrt{7}}} {8}}$$.

$\eta(36i)=\frac{a^{1/12}}{2^{29/16}*3^{5/6}*b^{1/18}}\Big(\sqrt{a}*\big(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}*b^{1/6}\big)-3^{1/4}*\sqrt{e}*b^{5/16}*c^{11/8}*d^{1/4}\Big)^{1/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=\sqrt{2}-1;  b=2-\sqrt{3}; c=\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4}; d=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2};  e=3^{1/4}-1.$$

$\eta(36i)=\frac{a^{1/4}}{2^{95/48}*3^{5/6}}\Big(A^{1/3}-\sqrt{6}\Big)^{1/3}
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$
$$A=d^{3}e^{6}b^{5/4}c^{9/2}+6\sqrt{6}$$
$$a=\sqrt{2}-1;b=2+\sqrt{3};c=\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4};d=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2};e=3^{1/4}-1$$

$\eta(40i)=\frac{\sqrt{d*e}} {2^{77/32}*\sqrt{5*\varphi}*a^{3/8}} (\sqrt{b}*a^{1/4}*c^{1/4}*\varphi^{3/4}-d^{3/2})*\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=\sqrt{2}-1;  b=5^{1/4}-\sqrt{2};  c=\sqrt{10}-3;  d=\frac{5^{1/4}-1}{\sqrt{2}};e=2^{1/4}-1; \varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$

$\eta(45i)=\frac{1} {12 \sqrt{5}} (\frac{\sqrt{5}-1} {2})^{5/2} (3+\sqrt{5}+(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}+60^{1/4}) (2+\sqrt{3})^{1/3}\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1} {2})^{2} (2-\sqrt{3})^{1/3} \frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}-15^{1/4}} {2}-1} {\sqrt{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1} {2})^{2} (2+\sqrt{3})^{1/3} \frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}+15^{1/4}} {2}+1}\big)^{2/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(45i)=\frac{1} {2.3. \sqrt{5}.a^{2/9}.b^{2/3}.\varphi^{7/6}} \Big(\sqrt{2}.a.b^{3}-3.b^{2}.\varphi^{2}.a^{2/3}+2\varphi^{6}\Big)^{1/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=2+\sqrt{3}$$

$$b=\frac {\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}+15^{1/4}}{2}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

$\eta(50i)=\frac{2^{1/8}}{40}\frac{Ab\Big(B^{2}\varphi^{3}+1\Big)^{3}}{d^{5}\varphi^{15}\Big(C^{2}-b\Big)}
\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$C=1+u^{1/5}+v^{1/5}$$

$$u=8d\big(+\sqrt{4-d^{2}}+\sqrt{2}d^{2}-d+\sqrt{2}\big)$$

$$v=8d\big(-\sqrt{4-d^{2}}+\sqrt{2}d^{2}-d+\sqrt{2}\big)$$

$$A=1+(4\varphi)^{1/5}\big(m^{1/5}+n^{1/5}\big)$$

$$m=3+\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}$$

$$n=3-\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}$$

$$B=1-(\frac{4}{\varphi})^{1/5}\big(r^{1/5}+s^{1/5}\big)$$

$$r=3+5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2}$$

$$s=3-5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2}$$

$$b=3+2*5^{1/4}$$

$$d=\frac{5^{1/4}+1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$\varphi$ is golden ratio.

$\eta(50i)≅\frac{2^{1/8}\varphi}{25\cdot D^{3}}\Big(a^{1/5}+b^{1/5}-1\Big)^{3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=4+\varphi+3\cdot 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\varphi}$$
$$b=4+\varphi-3\cdot 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\varphi}$$
$$D=\frac{5^{1/4}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$\eta(54i)=\frac{2^{5/8}}{3^{79/72}a^{1/72}b^{1/12}}\Big(\big(b^{3}\sqrt{3a}+(f^{1/3}-1)^{4}\big)^{1/3}-b(3a)^{1/6}\Big)^{1/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$
$$a=2-\sqrt{3};b=\sqrt{2}-3^{1/4};f=-\frac{5*12^{1/4}}{6}+\frac{7*\sqrt{3}}{9}+\frac{108^{1/4}}{6}+\frac{2}{3}$$

$\eta(63i)=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{7}}-\sqrt{3\sqrt{7}-7}}} {2^{13/8}.3.7^{7/16}}  \big( \frac{ 2  ( \sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}-252^{1/4}) (\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}+7^{1/4}} {2})^{4}} {\sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}+252^{1/4}) (\frac{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}} {2}) (\frac{\sqrt{3}+1} {\sqrt{2}})^{2/3}}  +  \frac{\sqrt{2}( \sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}+252^{1/4}) (\frac{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}} {2})^{1/2} (\frac{\sqrt{3}+1} {\sqrt{2}})^{1/3}}  {( \sqrt{3+\sqrt{7}}-252^{1/4}) (\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}+7^{1/4}} {2})^{2}}-3 \big)^{1/3} \frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(81i)=\frac{\Big(-3^{17/18}*a^{5/27}*b^{4/3}+\sqrt{ 2}\big(-3^{5/6}*a^{5/9}+\sqrt{2}*b^{1/3}*(\sqrt{6}*a^{1/6}+1)\big)^{1/3}*(\sqrt{2}*3^{5/6}*a^{5/9}+\sqrt{6}*a^{1/6}*b^{1/3}+b^{1/3})\Big)^{1/3}                          } {2*3^{49/27}*a^{19/162}*b^{1/9}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$b=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}*a^{1/6};$$
$$a=2-\sqrt{3}.$$

$\eta(90i)=\frac{D}{2^{11/8}3^{2/3}\sqrt{5\varphi}}\Big(-1+\Big(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}c^{12}\big(a^{4}b^{12}\varphi^{12}-\sqrt{a^{8}b^{24}\varphi^{24}-1}\big)^{3/2}}{2^{18}3^{2}D^{12}a^{13}b^{30}\varphi^{18}}\Big)^{1/3}\Big)^{1/3}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$a=2+\sqrt{3}$$

$$b=\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{15}}+15^{1/4}}{2}$$

$$c=540^{1/4}+60^{1/4}+2$$

$$D=\frac{5^{1/4}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$.

$\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

$\eta(100i)=\frac{2^{1/16}}{10}\frac{A b^{7/2}F^{11/2}}{G^{5/2}H^{1/4}d^{25/2}\varphi^{45/2}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$$H=\sqrt{2}F^{4}d^{20}G^{4}+2048b^{4}\varphi^{20}$$

$$G=C^{2}-b$$

$$F=1+\varphi^{3}B^{2}$$

$$C=1+u^{1/5}+v^{1/5}$$

$$u=8d\big(+\sqrt{4-d^{2}}+\sqrt{2}d^{2}-d+\sqrt{2}\big)$$

$$v=8d\big(-\sqrt{4-d^{2}}+\sqrt{2}d^{2}-d+\sqrt{2}\big)$$

$$A=1+(4\varphi)^{1/5}\Big(\big(3+\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}+ (\big(3-\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}\Big)$$

$$B=1-(\frac{4}{\varphi})^{1/5}\Big(\big(3+5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2}\big)^{1/5}+ (\big(3-5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2}\big)^{1/5}\Big)$$

$$b=3+2*5^{1/4}$$

$$d=\frac{5^{1/4}+1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$=\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

Encouraged by Gerald Edgar (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/442/gedgar)

I would like to implement the list of Dedekind’s $\eta$-function of the type $\eta(i\sqrt{n})$, with $n∈N$.

$\eta(i)=\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)}{2\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2^{11/8}}
\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{8}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)\Big)^{1/2}}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{3})=\frac{3^{1/8}}{2^{4/3}}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)\Big)^{3/2}}{\pi}$

$\eta(2i)=\frac{1}{2^{11/8}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{5})=\frac{1}{2^{5/4}5^{1/4}\varphi^{1/8}}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{20}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{7}{20}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{9}{20}\big)\Big)^{1/4}}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{6})=\frac{1}{2^{3/2}3^{1/4}}\Big(\sqrt{2}-1\Big)^{1/12}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{24}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{5}{24}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{7}{24}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{11}{24}\big)\Big)^{1/4}}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{7})=\frac{1}{2^{3/2}7^{1/8}}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{7}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2}{7}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{4}{7}\big) \Big)^{1/2}}{\pi}$

$\eta(2i\sqrt{2})=\frac{\Big(\sqrt{2}-1\Big)^{1/8}}{2^{7/4}}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{8}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)\Big)^{1/2}}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(3i)=\frac{\Big(2-\sqrt{3}\Big)^{1/12}}{2*3^{3/8}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)}{\pi^{3/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{10})=\frac{1}{4\big(5\varphi\big)^{1/4}}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{40}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{7}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{9}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{11}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{13}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{19}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{23}{40}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{37}{40}\big)\Big)^{1/4}}{\pi^{5/4}}$

with $\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{11})=\frac{1}{3*2^{11/6}*11^{1/8}}\Big(\frac{f^{1/3}-g^{1/3}+2}{a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}}\Big)\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{11}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{4}{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{5}{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{9}{11}\big) \Big)^{1/2}}{\pi^{3/2}}$

with
$f=3\sqrt{33}+17$;$g=3\sqrt{33}-17$;$a=1+\sqrt{\frac{11}{27}}$;$b=1- \sqrt{\frac{11}{27}}$.

$\eta(2i\sqrt{3})=\frac{3^{1/8}}{2^{7/4}}\big(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^{1/4}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^{3/2}}{\pi}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{13})=\frac{1}{2^{9/4}*13^{1/4}}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}\Big)^{1/8}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{52}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{7}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{9}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{11}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{15}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{17}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{19}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{25}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{29}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{31}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{47}{52}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{49}{52}\big)\Big)^{1/4}}{\pi^{7/4}}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{14})=\frac{1}{4*7^{1/4}}\Big(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{5-3\sqrt{2}}\Big)^{1/4}
\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{56}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{3}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{5}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{9}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{13}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{15}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{19}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{23}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{25}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{27}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{39}{56}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{45}{56}\big)\Big)^{1/8}}{\pi}$

$\eta(i\sqrt{15})=\frac{1}{2^{5/4}3^{1/4}5^{1/4}}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\Big)^{5/12}\frac{\Big(\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{15}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2}{15}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{4}{15}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{8}{15}\big)\Big)^{1/4}}{\pi^{3/4}}$

Comment: A genereric method is to set $f_n(z)=\Delta(nz)/\Delta(z)\in \mathbb{C}(X_0(n))$ then $\prod_{ad=n,b\bmod n} (Y-f_n(\frac{az+b}{dn}))=g_n(1/j(z),Y)$ with $g_n\in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y] $ computable from the Fourier expansions. Then from $j(i) = 1728$ you have a polynomial whose $1/f_n(i)$ is a root, from which you can find the minimal polynomial of $f_n(i)^{1/24} = \eta(ni)/\eta(i)$ and since $\mathbb{Q}(i,f_n(i)) \subset \mathbb{Q}(i,j(i),j(ni))/\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is abelian $\mathbb{Q}(f_n(i)^{1/24})/\mathbb{Q}$ is radical and you obtain the expressions you mentioned

Comment: My intent is only to have "physically" the radical, written in unit factors, which generates the value of Dedekind's function, as it is aesthetically appealing, beautiful!  Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: How did you arrive at these values in radical form? I think the desired calculations would be formidable to do by hand (unless one is Ramanujan).

Comment: You're very kind! Thank you

Comment: See related https://mathoverflow.net/q/260786/454 with $j(i\sqrt{6}\;)$ and $\eta(i\sqrt{6}\;)$.

Comment: @GEdgar-I just found the values of $\eta(i\sqrt{6})$ and $\eta(i\sqrt{3/2}$ inl https://mathoverflow.net/q/260786/454

Comment: @giuseppemancò: I checked $\eta(30i)$ because I needed it for something. Unfortunately, it is **incorrect**. (I checked it with Mathematica and also used an Integer Relations algorithm to see if there was an error in the exponents.)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III - Using “Pari” , $\eta(30i)= 0.000388203203926766247232$;
Using “Derive”, “\eta(30i)= 0.0003882032039267662472297$.

Comment: @giuseppemancò: We compare various evaluations using $22$ digits accuracy, $$\begin{align}
\text{Mathematica} &= 0.000388203203926766247232\\
\text{Pari} &= 0.000388203203926766247232\\
\text{Derive} &= 0.00038820320392676624722970\\
\text{formula} &= 0.00038820320392676624722987
\end{align}$$ Were you using only $20$ digits of accuracy? If so, then your formula is only a very good _approximation_.  Pls re-check using more digits of accuracy. Thanks.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III - I posted a new version.

Comment: @giuseppemancò The new version for $\eta(30i)$ missed a denominator $4$. So I corrected it and marked it blue. It is now correct to more than $300$ digits accuracy.

Comment: @TITO PIEZAS III – Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3064707/72031) one can easily verify the value of $\eta(9i)$.

We have by definition $$\eta(9i)=e^{-3\pi/4}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-e^{-18n\pi})$$ And using the answer linked above we can see that $$\eta(9i)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{18+6\sqrt{3}}-3}}{6}\cdot\frac{\Gamma (1/4)}{\pi^{3/4}}$$ One can use a little bit of algebra to verify that $$\sqrt{6}(2+\sqrt{3})^{1/6}=\sqrt[3]{18+6\sqrt{3}}$$ and get the value of $\eta(9i)$ mentioned in your question.

The modular equation given in the linked answer can be used to evaluate $\eta(27i)$ given the values of $\eta(3i),\eta(9i)$ and in general one can get the values of $\eta(3^ni)$ in similar fashion. Using $\eta(2i),\eta(6i)$ one can also verify the value of $\eta(18i)$. You should use the value of $\eta(7i)$ (given in linked question in your post) and $\eta(63i)$ of your post together with Ramanujan's modular equation to get the value of $\eta(21i)$ and add it to your table.

Remaining set of values of eta function in your question require more effort to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, now I try to calculate $ \eta (21i) $. I just posted $ \eta (32i) $.

Comment: @giuseppemancò Why do you care of $\eta(ni)$ for a few particular values of $n$, why not look instead at the general formulas valid for every $n$ ? Do you know that $\Bbb{Q}(i,j(Ni))/\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is an abelian extension and how to find its [minimal polynomial](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/189.pdf) ?

Answer (score 1):

Values of $\eta(mi\sqrt{n})/\eta(i\sqrt{n})$ can be obtained up to a factor of elliptic functions. For example, let
$$
k_{27}= \frac{\left ( 3-c_{27} \right ) }{c_{27}(1+c_{27})}
\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}  }{4},c_{27}=\sqrt{3+2^{4/3}(1+2^{1/3})}.
$$
The singular value should be
$$
K(k_{27})
=\frac{\sqrt{3+2^{4/3}(1+2^{1/3})}}{3^{3/4}\cdot2^{7/3}\pi} 
\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^3.
$$
And
$\eta(i\sqrt{n})=\sqrt{\frac{2K(k_{n})}{\pi} } 
\cdot2^{-1/3}k_{n}^{1/6}(1-k_{n}^2)^{1/12}.$
For $n=17$, we calculate
$$
k_{17}
=\frac{\sqrt{1+c_{17}}-\sqrt{1-c_{17}}  }{2},
c_{17}=20+5\sqrt{17}-8\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{17}}-6\sqrt{2\sqrt{17}-2}
$$
and
$$
K(k_{17})=\frac{\left ( \sqrt{17}-4  \right )^{1/8}
\left ( 1+\sqrt{17} +\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{17} }  \right )^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi} }{
2^{9/2}\sqrt{17} }
\left [ \prod_{m=1}^{68}\Gamma\left ( \frac{m}{68}  \right )^{\left(\frac{-68}{m}\right)}   \right ]^{1/8}.
$$
$\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$ is Legendre-Kronecker symbol.
For $n=18$ similarly,
$$
k_{18}=\left ( \sqrt{2}-  1\right )^3
\left ( 2-\sqrt{3}  \right )^2,
$$
$$
K(k_{18})
=\frac{\left ( \sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2} -1  \right ) \left ( \sqrt{2}+1  \right )^{1/2} }{
3\cdot2^{13/4}\sqrt{\pi} }\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right ).
$$