# A modular equation of 11th degree of Dedekind's $\eta$ function.

Tags: radicals, modular-forms

Regarding the Post
[Additional values of Dedekind's $\eta$ function in radical form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101157/additional-values-of-dedekinds-eta-function-in-radical-form)

I wrote the equation that has as root the value $\frac{\eta(11i)} {\eta(i)}$ that is missing.

Can someone help me solve (in radical form) the following equation, whose solution is the value of Dedekind's modular $\frac{\eta(11i)} {\eta(i)}$ function?

$$x^{24}-\frac{90}{11^{5}} x^{12}+\frac{480}{11^{7}}x^{8}+\frac{288}{11^{9}} x^{4}-\frac{1}{11^{11}}=0$$

where

$$x=\frac{\eta(11\ i)}{\eta(i)}.$$

This equation comes from the work of L. Kiepert and specializes for the value reported in the title of the application. My intent is to find the solution in closed form.

Comment: I use the program "Derive" and the values is x = 0.073085799269177192524967047801357734832236759435876091870009595338428953696284190325787697249450777, the program PARI indeed x=0.073085799269177192524967047801357734832.

Comment: I think this approximation value is acceptable!

Comment: Seems clear to me.

Comment: See the similar questions for [13th degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205373), 
[17th degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205410),
[19th degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205515),
[23rd degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205555).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Mathematica I found a solution. Let
$\ p := 11,\ $ $s := \sqrt{p},\ $ $x := \eta(p\ i)/\eta(i),\  $
$x_0 := (p\,x^2)^2,\ $ $f(x) := x^3 -4sx^2 + (88-12s)x + (33-10s).\ $
Then $\ f(x_0) = 0.\ $ Solve for $\ x_0\ $ using
$\ c_1 := 22-9s,\ $ $c_2 := 21365-6324s,\ $ $c_3 := -3861+1490s,\ $
$r_2 := 9s\sqrt{3c_2},\ $ $r_3 := \sqrt[3]{(c_3-r_2)/2}.\ $
Then $\ x_0 = (4s+4c_1/r_3-r_3)/3 \approx 0.003452370313107857. $

Comment: @OscarLanzi They are two different numbers. One is $x$ root of degree 24 polynomial. The other is $x_0 = (p\,x^2)^2$ root of a cubic. I voted to close by mistake.

Comment: So I'm looking at $121x^4$.  Seems to work.

Comment: Thank you! I posted $\eta(11i)$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101157/additional-values-of-dedekinds-eta-function-in-radical-form.