# A modular equation of 17th degree of Dedekind’s $\eta$ function.

Tags: radicals, modular-forms

Regarding the Post [Additional values of Dedekind's $\eta$ function in radical form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101157/additional-values-of-dedekinds-eta-function-in-radical-form)

I wrote the equation that has as root the value $\frac{\eta(17i)}{\eta(i)}$  that is missing.

Can someone help me solve (in radical form) the following equation, whose solution is the value of Dedekind’s modular $\frac{\eta(17i)}{\eta(i)}$ function?

$$x^{16}+\frac{1}{17}x^{14}-\frac{7}{ 17^{2}}x^{12}+\frac{62}{17^{3}}x^{10}+\frac{134}{17^{4}}x^{8}+\frac{10}{17^{5}}x^{6}+\frac{1061}{17^{6}}x^{4}-\frac{259}{17^{7}}x^{2}+\frac{1}{17^{8}}=0$$
where

$$x=\frac{\eta(17i)}{\eta(i)}.$$

Note:  "This equation comes from the work of L. Kiepert and specializes for the value reported in the title of the application. My intent is to find the solution in closed form."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mathematica I found a solution. Let
$\ p = 17,\ q = p^{1/4},\ $ $x = \eta(p\ i)/\eta(i),\ $ $x_0 = p\,x^2,\ $
$ a = (1+q-3q^2+q^3)/4,\ $ $b = 4-4q+q^2\ $
and $\ f(x) := x^2 + ax + b.\ $ Then $\ f(x_0) = 0.\ $
 Solving the quadratic gives the solution
 $\ x_0 = (-a - \sqrt{a^2-4b})/2 \approx 0.0039240864728144377.$

Comment: With the values you assign to a and b $x _ {0} = 0.0009660570573631175799$ and not 0.0039240..... (I don't understand!)

Comment: Oops! Missed a division by 4 for $a$. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I immediately arrange the value in the sort of table!