# A modular equation of 23rd degree of Dedekind’s $\eta$ function.

Tags: radicals, modular-forms

Regarding the Post [Additional values of Dedekind's $\eta$ function in radical form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101157/additional-values-of-dedekinds-eta-function-in-radical-form)
 I wrote the equation that has as root the value $\frac{\eta(23i)}{\eta(i)}$  that is missing.

Can someone help me solve (in radical form) the following equation, whose solution is the value of Dedekind’s modular $\frac{\eta(23i)}{\eta(i)}$ function?

$$x^{48}+\frac{684}{23^{5}}x^{36}-\frac{2496}{23^{7}}x^{32}+\frac{10944}{23^{9}}x^{28}+\frac{3826738}{23^{11}}x^{24}-\frac{31577472}{23^{13}}x^{20}+$$
$$\frac{785460096}{23^{15}}x^{16}-\frac{2112004548}{23^{17}}x^{12}+\frac{4240221504}{23^{19}}x^{8}+\frac{18998208}{23^{21}}x^{4}-\frac{1}{23^{23}}=0$$

where

$$x=\frac{\eta(23i)}{\eta(i)}.$$

This equation comes from the work of L. Kiepert and specializes for the value reported in the title of the application. My intent is to find the solution in closed form.

Comment: $x\approx \frac1{316}$

Comment: @Peter Foreman-Excellent approximation!

Comment: @Somos-That's a good question! But I don't have the answer.--By the way, what news about Berndt?

Comment: @Somos-You should try to solve the equation and you will see that the solution is very accurate!

Comment: Your equation is correct and it splits into two sextics over $\mathbb{Q}[23]$ but solution in radicals is not possible. That is, if $s=\sqrt{23}$,and $y=(sx)^4$, then
$0 = y^6 + 4sy^5 +(184-108s)y^4 +(-2070+548s)y^3 +(142232+8820s)y^2 +(-132480+27796s)y +(264845-55224s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After substitution $x^4\to x,$ we get a 12-degree equation that factors into cubics over the rationals extended with $\sqrt{23}$ and $\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt[4]{23\,}$. Solving the cubic equation, we get

$$\small\begin{align}
\!\!\frac{\eta(23i)}{\eta(i)}&=\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\sqrt[4]{\frac{2\cdot 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\alpha }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\alpha }} \left(360 \sqrt{23}+9 \sqrt{2} \cdot23^{3/4}-1426-525 \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt[4]{23}\right)-8 \sqrt{23}+6 \sqrt{2}\,\sqrt[4]{23}
   \left(3+\sqrt{23}\right)}{6348}},
\end{align}$$ 
where
$$\small\alpha =32 \sqrt{23} \left(38-9 \sqrt{3}\right)+2484 \left(9 \sqrt{3}-4\right)-9 \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt[4]{23} \,\left(717-454 \sqrt{3}+139 \sqrt{23}+62 \sqrt{69}\right).$$